# undefined reference to `Counter::valueChanged(int)'

Tags: qt

i'm trying to learn qt.this is my first example that I'm practicing.but i have this error:C:\Qt2\Qt5.2.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\recognize_signal_slot\main.cpp:19: error: undefined reference to `Counter::valueChanged(int)'

I don't know what I should do..someone told me you should put your class in header file.but I couldn't understand what he said.can anyone tell me step by step.thank you so much.

here is my code in main.cpp :

```
     #include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QObject>

class Counter : public QObject
{

    int m_value;
public:
    int value() const { return m_value; }
public slots:
    void setValue(int value);
signals:
    void valueChanged(int newValue);
};
void Counter::setValue(int value)
{
    if (value != m_value) 
    {
        m_value = value;
        emit valueChanged(value);
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    Counter d, b;
      QObject::connect(&d, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
                       &b, SLOT(setValue(int)));

     d.setValue(12);  // a.value() == 12, b.value() == 12

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [What's Wrong?]

You signals & slots are **not** invoked by [**Meta-Object-Compiler (MOC)**](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/moc.html).

Suggested reading: [*Why Does Qt Use Moc for Signals and Slots?*](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/why-moc.html).

---

## [Solution]

Step 1. Add `Q_OBJECT` macro to the `QObject` derivatives that use signals & slots.

```
    class Counter : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT     // <-----HERE

        int m_value;
    public:
        int value() const { return m_value; }
    public slots:
        void setValue(int value);
    signals:
        void valueChanged(int newValue);
    };
```

Step 2. move your class declaration to `counter.h` and implementation to `counter.cpp`. Since **MOC** searches **header files** that contain `Q_OBJECT`, it's better to keep your QObject classes and main well separate, even for a small test project.

Step 3. Clean all ---> **run qmake** ---> rebuild   (**qmake** will automatically call **MOC** to translate signals & slots syntax into compilable C++ code)

Comment: could you please tell me how I can define class in another file?

Comment: Right click on your project: choose `add new class` and type class name, Qt Creator will generate `.h` and `.cpp` file for you.